# Next.js get stuck when loading page

Tags: javascript, next.js, localhost

I have a Next.js application that stopped working and I can't figure out why. When I run the project on my localhost `npm run dev`, the application doesn't load.

I was inspecting the *network* tab and I found out that the `main.js`, `app.js` and `analysis.js` (my home page) keep loading forever (I've waited a few minutes):

[image]

The weird thing is that this project was working just fine yesterday.

I tried clearing the cache, opening in a incognito window, using a different browser and nothing seems to work. I also tried to clear the project, install all the NPM dependencies and run the app again, but still got the same error.

Another weird thing is that it works fine on production, when I deploy it. I even tried to checkout my `master` branch (the live version that is working) and run it locally, but same issue happened.

There are no error messages on the console or the terminal.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

PS: This happens with every page of the project, I tried different routes and it's always the same.

Comment: When you cleared the cache, did you delete the `.next` folder?

Comment: I noticed under the *Initiator* column in your screenshot that `main.js` and `_app.js` list `analysis` as their initiator (on my machine `(index)` is listed instead for `main.js` and `_app.js`). Maybe there's something in `analysis.js` that's getting "stuck" on your local setup for whatever reason? Are you running some type of benchmarker/profiler?

Comment: Ah thanks for the insight @MarkG! I will take a look in my `analysis.js`. And I am not running any benchmarker.

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox, I forgot to delete the `.next` folder. I did that and now I am getting a different error on build that helped me figure out what is wrong. It's actually a typescript issue in another file that `analysis.js` is importing...

Comment: It seems any of your page component trying to fetch the data using next js server side fetching technique locally, that's why its keep on loading in local but running smoothly on the production.

Comment: If anyone arrives here and can't figure out why, consider you may have throttling turned on in the Network tab. Not that I would know from experience or anything